# not able to Log the message in activemq using log4j2

Tags: java, logging, jms, activemq-classic, log4j2

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;


public class Producer {
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;
    private static String QUEUE_NAME = "kesaven";
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Producer.class.getName());
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException
{
    //System.out.println(url);
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    //TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("My first log message to queue");
    logger.info("My first log message to queue");
    //producer.send(message);
    //System.out.println("Sentage '" + message.getText() + "'");
    connection.close();



}

}
```

i am trying to log the message to a queue using log4j2 and activemq. i am using log4j2.3 and for queue i am using activemq 5.9.0 . i am able to see exception message in queue not the message i sent. Following is the error message in queue

> javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content.
>   Serializable class not available to broker. Reason:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent$LogEventProxy

Comment: Following is my maven dependecy pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
 <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
 <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: i am also getting this warning message in console

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: Following is my log4j2.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
  <Appenders>
<JMS name="jmsQueue" destinationBindingName="logQueue"
        factoryName="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
        factoryBindingName="ConnectionFactory"
        providerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="jmsQueue"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Answer (score 1):

What appender are you using to write the data to ActiveMQ? I would suggest that instead of using Java serialization to write the log event that you serialize it to JSON, use the RFC5424 layout or some other format that doesn't require the Log4j2 jars when reading the events.

Comment: I am using jms appender

Comment: The JMSAppender allows you to use any Layout you want but defaults to the SerializedLayout. Pick something that will work better for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Log4event is put on the queue , can you check if you have the log4j2 jars available on the broker end.

Comment: yes i am not able to see the log4j2 class files in the activemq jar, how to solve this isse , so that if i log using log4j2 in java side i should be getting the message in queue without any issue , taking in account that we dont have log4j2 classes inside the activemq jar.by default we have log4j1.2 classes in activemq jar but i need to implement using log4j2!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I added the following jars from log4j2 to the activeMQ server /lib directory to make this work

log4j-api-2.6.1,
log4j-core-2.6.1

I logged Strings only, if I tried to log ObjectMessages, the queue entry would not open in the Queue manager view, the JSP failed.

Comment: Does the Queue manager view process have the log4j2 jars in its classpath?

Comment: I used the following link to try to allow the classes I wanted to be viewed as ObjectMessages.  http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html.  I am viewing the queues through Chrome using  http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp .  Where else might the jar files need to be?